# Error when converting string to date object from command line in Python

Tags: python, datetime

When I run the following code, I don't see any problems:

```
as_of_date = '10-16-17'
today = datetime.datetime.strptime(as_of_date, '%m-%d-%y').date()
type(today)
print(today)

Out:  datetime.date
Out:  2017-10-16
```

However, when I run a script named `GetStats.py` that takes several arguments from the command line, I get an error.

The command line consists of 5 arguments and looks as follows:

```
python   GetStats.py   Client_A.cfg   30   -d   10-16-17
```

The last argument ("10-16-17") on the command line represents a date.

The code in the GetStats.py script is as follows:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time, date

as_of_date = sys.argv[4]
today = datetime.datetime.strptime(as_of_date, '%m-%d-%y').date()

print (today)
```

The code doesn't hit the print statement and instead shows the following error:

```
type 'exceptions.AttributeError'
```

Does anyone see the mistake when I try to pass that date from the command line?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that as much detail as your have in your error message, or is there more? If there is more, please provide it.

Comment: Yes, that is as much detail as the error message is showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your import:

`from datetime import datetime` and then you try to call `datatime.datetime.strptime`

By doing this, you're trying to call the function `datetime.datetime.datetime.strptime` which doesn't exist.

Therefore, to fix this change `datetime.datetime` to simply `datetime` in your code.